# How much space (in binary/in memory) does a Java interface take?

Tags: java, interface, sizeof

I'm trying to understand how much space a java interface will take up, both on disk in the binary, and on a per instantiated object basis. Obligatory "every JVM implementation may be different" disclaimer, I am more interested not in a 100% exact answer, but in understanding the essentials of how this is handled.

If we assume a simple interface (no static final vars, no default implementations), how much space does this take in binary? I assume the human readable class name will need to be stored, for debugging/reflection, plus possibly some unique class identifier? When an object that implements this interface is instantiated, how many extra bytes of overhead does the interface add to the in-memory representation of the object, if any?

Comment: This isn't a very meaningful question and any answers will be different over time as the classfile format changes and the JVM implementations change.  It probably will have different answers on different platforms.  Maybe if you explained what an "answer" would give you and why it's important to know.  Certainly the only answer to _"... how many extra bytes of overhead..."_ is "it depends".

Comment: It's not a cop-out answer, it's *the only valid answer*. SO isn't just concerned with answering one person's question today, it's a long-term repository of information. What's accurate about the current latest Java may not be relevant tomorrow, and may not be relevant today to someone else using a different version of Java.

Comment: Read the JVM bytecode spec.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html

Comment: And yet, somehow, this question has produced two useful pieces of information, which are worth knowing and will be relevant for years to come. 1) that the JVM bytecode spec answers part of the question, and 2) that there is currently apparently no overhead on a per object basis. Funny how that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how much space a java interface will take up, both on disk in the binary, and on a per instantiated object basis.

**On disk in the binary:**
*Definitive answer:* See file size of `.class` file.
*Short answer:* It depends, as [Jim Garrison said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44373921/how-much-space-in-binary-in-memory-does-a-java-interface-take#comment75749063_44373921).
*Long answer:* It depends on: length of package name, length of interface name, number of methods, length of method names, number of parameters, type of parameters, length of parameter names, type of return type, whether debug information is included, version of bytecode, *... and more ...*

**On a per instantiated object basis:**
None.